# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Poco::SystemException'

Tags: c++, exception

Sometimes (about 1 out of 100 runs), my program terminates with this message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Poco::SystemException'
  what():  System exception
```

my code is not the one catching the exception (all my catches are more verbose), and I am not sure where it's caught.
it's very likely that the exception does contain a useful message, but it's not returned through the what() method but by the displayText() method.

The string "terminate called after throwing an instance of" has ~600k in Google, so it's probably printed by code inserted by the compiler or by some common library (pthread?).
I only seen this error message when the program ran on Linux (never on Windows).

anyone knows in what code this uncaught exception is caught?

Comment: Yes, a library generates that message, although that's not the pthread library, it is the C++ library that comes with the compiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> anyone knows in what code this uncaught exception is caught?

An uncaught exception is—by definition—not caught anywhere.

If an exception cannot be handled, the C++ exception mechanism will call `std::terminate()` (see include header `<exception>`), which will call a customizable termination handler. On your platform, the standard termination handler prints the output of `std::exception::what()` (which Poco's exceptions inherit from). Unfortunately, the way Poco's exceptions are designed, this will not contain any useful information.

There are multiple ways an exception cannot be handled:

- No suitable `catch()` handler is found and the unwinding mechanism exits `main()`. You can try wrapping your `main()` code in `try...catch` to print the exception's `displayText()`.
- A function exits with an exception that does not match its exception specification (`... functionname(...) throw(...)`). This will call `std::unexpected()` which in turn will call `std::terminate()` (by default).
- An exception is thrown from within a destructor that is called during the unwinding process of another exception. Never throw exceptions in destructors!
- An exception is thrown while trying to create the original exception object. Never throw exceptions in custom exception classes!

When using Poco threads and a thread is terminated by an unhandled exception, Poco will invoke its internal [`ErrorHandler`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.ErrorHandler.html) and the program will not exit, so I doubt that this is a threading issue.

Comment: Thanks.

for easier debugging, I hacked Exception::what() in Poco to print the displayText() to stdout.
this makes it possible to see the actual message of uncaught exceptions.
I am still working on figuring out the actual cause, the exception is about not being able to lock a mutex, and is probably thrown somehow from some destructor.

Comment: turns out the bug is IN Poco ErrorHandler, or at least one bug.
check this out:

http://pocoproject.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=1308&p=2793#p2793

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I had used a try catch block in the run function of the Poco::Runnable class. I removed the try catch block from this class and used a derivative of Poco::ErrorHandler class to handle the errors. After this I stopped getting this error.